# Reach last element of a hierarchy

Tags: java, list, ldap

I have a hierarchy with employees and managers. A manager can have others managers under him and so on... until the last level which is the employees. What I need is that for a specific manager I want to get every manager and employees under him no matter how much level there is under him. These managers and employees come from a LDAP. Each user have an attribute called "manager" (which is the id of the manager) and they are identified thanks to their "uid"

For now I'm able to get every managers from a manager and the employees under them but I don't know how to do it without knowing the number of level under the first manager. Here is what I have :

```
public static ArrayList<String> getUsersByManager(String str) throws NamingException{
    String baseDN = "ou=Internal,ou=People,o=group";
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
    String[] attributeFilter = {"uid"};
    sc.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
    sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String filter = "(&(manager=uid="+str+",ou=Internal,ou=People,o=Group))";
    DirContext contexte = Connexion();
    NamingEnumeration results = contexte.search(baseDN, filter, sc);
    while(results.hasMore()){
        SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) results.next();
        Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
        list.add(attrs.get("uid").get().toString());
        list2.add(attrs.get("uid").get().toString());
    }
    for(String s : list){
        filter = "(&(manager=uid="+s+",ou=Internal,ou=People,o=Group))";
        NamingEnumeration result = contexte.search(baseDN, filter, sc);
        while(result.hasMore()){
            SearchResult search = (SearchResult) result.next();
            Attributes attr = search.getAttributes();
            list2.add(attr.get("uid").get().toString());
        }
    }
    contexte.close();
    return list2;
    }
```

Can you please tell me how can I do ? I can add more explanations if it's not clear enough

Comment: The solution is called recursion. If you don’t know about it, it’s a bit tricky, but learnable, and once you’ve grasped it, you’ll probably love it. Go find the tutorials on recursion.

Comment: @OleV.V. Ok thanks you, I'll check this, do you have any good tutorials to start ?

Comment: Not really. :-) I learned this stuff in university before the existence of WWW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has neither been compiled nor tested (I have neither got a `Connextion` method nor an LDAP server to test against). I hope it gets you started. You should still read about recursion in order to understand the code.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getUsersByManager(String manager) throws NamingException {
    String baseDN = "ou=Internal,ou=People,o=group";
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
    String[] attributeFilter = { "uid" };
    sc.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
    sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String filter = "(&(manager=uid=" + manager + ",ou=Internal,ou=People,o=Group))";
    DirContext contexte = Connexion();
    NamingEnumeration results = contexte.search(baseDN, filter, sc);
    while (results.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) results.next();
        Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
        String user = attrs.get("uid").get().toString();
        list.add(user);
        // recursive call:
        ArrayList<String> usersManaged = getUsersByManager(user);
        list.addAll(usersManaged);
    }
    contexte.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly, I've read some tutorials about recursion and it's really usefull